# php counting reply on post

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am having a problem regarding counting rows of reply on post. i am doing a project a simple forum script. i just want to have a reply count on my forum here is the script i made.

```
$replyCount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM topic_reply WHERE tid = '".$topic_id."' ");

$row = mysql_fetch_object($replyCount);
$reply_count_rows = $row->total;
```

The problem is i get the same results for the 2 different topics
it goes something like this

`Topic 1 / Reply 2`

`Topic 2 / Reply 2`

the `**Topic 1**` has 2 Replies and the `**Topic 2**` has no or 0 replies but i am getting same values on both Topics

Hope someone can help me on this thanks in advance.

Comment: $row1->total or $row->total?

Comment: Don't use the deprecated mysql, use mysqli or PDO. And that little piece of code doesn't really help -- where is $row1 coming from?

Comment: What if you run the query manually?

Comment: Sorry about the $row1 its typographical error.. its supposed both $row..

Comment: @Explosion Pills. the query is running good and i am getting results.. the thing confusing me is about the replies on each topic that gives me same results on all topics i made.. 

Here is the image 
http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg26/hinayupaks/post_zpsb75cb600.jpg

The General Discussions have 3 replies and the WYD OFF Topic has no replies but the results is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore that you're using a deprecated function, and that your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Try this:

```
 $replyCount = mysql_query("
 SELECT
     IFNULL(COUNT(id), 0) AS total
 FROM
      topic_reply
 GROUP BY
       tid");
```

Remove the `WHERE` clause in your query if you want to know the count for each TID.

By filtering the FID, you will only be counting for THAT specific TID.

See this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea106/4

Comment: Here is the Full code
     $replyCount = mysql_query("SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(id), 0) AS total FROM topic_reply WHERE tid = '".$topic_id."' ");

<div class="thread-status">Replies: <?php echo $reply_count_rows; ?></div>



     $row = mysql_fetch_object($replyCount);
     $reply_count_rows = $row1->total;

Comment: i actually mislead myself about those codes.. sorry but dont mind the $row and $row1 i corrected it already and change to $row both... The rows i have in my table name 'topic_reply' is ID, TID, MESSAGE, AUTHORID .. .. .. TID is the group id from the TOPIC table. i want the replies from each rows grouped by TID and get different results for every TID Lets say i have 2 different TID's Like 11 and 12 TID 11 has 2 Replies and TID 12 has no reply... the problem is i get same results on that 2 Different TID's

Comment: You cannot get results from two different TIDs with your current SQL query, because you're filtering by a specific TID.

Comment: ok man i guess you are right.. will remove that functions for the meantime.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with $topic_id. Echo it and check if it is the correct one for each topic you are accessing.

And please, as suggested in other comments, use PDO and prevent SQL injections. Read up on them if you are unfamiliar.